# Time complexity of a recursive function having two nested for loop inside it

Tags: for-loop, recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory, code-complexity

```
function recursion(n){
    if n==0
        return

    for(let i=0; i < n;i++){
        for(let j=0; j< n; j++){
        console.log('*');
    } 
}
  recursion(n-1);

}
recursion(100);
```

What is the Time complexity of this code??

O(n^2log(n))

O(n^3)

O(n^2)

Or if it has any other time complexity, please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1):

this will run

```
count - inner loop 1  inner loop 2
100   - 0-99 (100x)   0-99 (100x)  - 100 * 100 
99    - 0-98 (99x)    0-98 (99x)  - 99 * 99
98    - 0-97 (98x)    0-97 (98x)  - 98 * 98
...
1     - 0-0 (1x)     0-0 (1x)     - 1 * 1
```

this is a sum of squares problem as you can see
and the formula is - (N * (N + 1) * (2N + 1)) / 6
see url - [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222061352/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56920.html) for complete explanation

The answer is : O(k(k+1)(2k+1)  / 6 ) to simplify the function: tested... c#

```
 private static void loop(long n)
    {
        for (long x = n; x > 0; x--)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
                {
                    { dosomething here }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O(n^3) is the answer
because for each i = 0 to n there will be j from 0 to n .. like for i=0 , j = 0 to n.
for i=1 , j = 0 to n.
similarly for all i.
so
(0)n+(1)n+...n*n
(n(n+1)/2) * n
and sice we are using recursive function which is getting arguments n times
so
n*n*n

Comment: But what will be the role of recursive function?                                                                  
If I write the same function as a single function  then the answer will be same right ?                                                 function simple(n){

    for(let i=0; i < n;i++){
        for(let j=0; j< n; j++){
        console.log('*');
    } 
}
}                                                                                                                                                          simple(100);

Comment: yes its right. recursive function increases time complexity it is not necessary to use recursive function.